# Testing javascript nodejs + socket.io backend server with Travis CI

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, functional-testing, travis-ci

I have got a small backend server in nodejs which is using socket.io to connect with client and on the other side is uses google api to delivery data.
Is there a good way to write tests and still use something like Travis CI?
In a local enviroment there is no problem with doing test with a fake user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have a couple options.

- Write unit style tests against your JavaScript frontend with something like [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) or [Yeti](http://yeti.cx/), both of which support Travis CI. This would involve mocking out the socket.io API in your frontend code with something like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/).
- Borrow some concepts from [Laika](http://arunoda.github.io/laika/concepts.html) which uses [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to execute browser code against your app running in its own process. Laika is for testing client/server interactions similar to what you're doing.

In either case you probably want to mock out the google API while testing using [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) or [Nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock).

Answer (score 0):

Just answered a question using nock but was too sleepy to care to check the old date. =/

See if this answer can help you in any way about HTTP mocking with nock:

[Simulate HTTP responses to test a node.js HTTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759394/simulate-http-responses-to-test-a-node-js-http-client/22343062#22343062)